# How to receive an array from a model inside another model? (mongoose) (mongoDB)

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have an order model/schema, and my goal is that in this model in "list", I receive the information from the model cart in array format. How could I do this using ref?

cart model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CartSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        note: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        price: {
            type: Number,
            required: false,
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );
  
module.exports = mongoose.model("Cart", CartSchema);
```

order

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        list: {
            name: String,
            notes: String,
        },
        totalAmount: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
        },
        payment: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        address: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        addressNote: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );
  
module.exports = mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);
```

Basically receive in array format the information of the model cart in "list" in model order

Answer (score 1):

You should define your `list` as an array of `ObjectId`s referring to the `Cart` model:

```
const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
      list: [{
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Cart'
      }],
      ...
  });
```

Then, to retrieve the values in `list`, just populate the `Order`:

```
Order.find({}).populate('list').exec();
```

Comment: Can I send several "cart" within the list?

Comment: For example, can I send more than one cart to this array that will be added? Or just one?

Comment: `list` is declared as an array so yes, you can add multiple `Cart` references to it

Comment: How can I do this in postman? For example

Comment: In theory in "list" I should put the cart id I want, right? If I want more than one cart, how can I add more than one id? (postman)

Comment: You can pass an array of `ObjectId`s and add them with a `$addToSet` operation to the `list`. For more see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/